# Running an R Program on Azure Webapp

Tags: r, azure

I've been using R 3.4.3 for Mac OS X to run a program which sets up and solves some complex matrix equations. I've been running the program manually on my laptop up until now and I'd like to finally set it up in my [Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) (where my website is hosted) and configure it to run daily.  Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Back in 2018, I installed R 3.3.3 as a Site Extension, similar to
   what is explained [here](https://medium.com/@cednewein/r-microservices-on-microsoft-azure-part-1-ff934380e5a1). However, R is no longer supported by
   Microsoft as a Site Extension and can no longer be installed that
   way (as explained [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/932)).
2. This weekend, I started experimenting with Microsoft Azure Machine
   Learning Studio.  There, Microsoft offers an "R Language Module"
   where you can click and drag "Execute R Script" into your experiment
   and add R code to it.  I really like this option a lot because
   Microsoft has already loaded up many of the popular R packages and
   you don't need to bother with doing that in your program.  However,
   the R script container is limited to 27,000 characters and my
   program exceeds that by a long shot.  I *could* consider breaking up
   my program into smaller chunks and try to figure out how to connect
   multiple R scripts together.

At this point, my strong preference is to be able to keep my program intact and simply run it by calling a command line (e.g., `R CMD BATCH "test.R"`) statement and kicking it off using a [Logic App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/#features).  But I cannot figure out how to install R onto my Azure Web App.

If anyone has any experience with this or has some ideas, I'd love to hear them.  Thank you!

Comment: This is not a code specific problem. S.O. is really best suited to Code related issues not discussions like a forum.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to run R scripts in Azure and they are well documented in Architecture Guide which you can find here:

- [R developer’s guide to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/technology-choices/r-developers-guide#azure-notebooks)

So in your case you should probably convert your code to Jupiter notebooks an run it from Databricks. It is the most stable, easy to implement and production ready option from the list.

- [Azure Databricks for R developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/sparkr/?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fazure-databricks%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json)

If your project is small or it is just little task, you can try with Azure Notebooks or even with Azure SQL Server, especially when your data reside in there. But for now both of this solutions are in preview so it’s not recommended to production workloads.

- [Azure SQL Database Machine Learning Services with R (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-machine-learning-services-overview)
- [Manage and configure projects in Azure Notebooks Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notebooks/configure-manage-azure-notebooks-projects#compute-tier)

There are of course Data Science Virtual Machines, but it require more effort to integrate it with environment and doesn’t seem like your use case.